# Magento and mySQL on different server

Tags: mysql, magento, configuration, magento2, rhel

I need to configure Magento 2.4.5 on RHEL. I need recommendation/best practices for below:

1. Should I go with RHEL 8.6 or 9.0? Don't want to go with Ubuntu or CentOS.
2. Should I host the database on a separate server, rather than running the database server and the
   web server on the same machine?
3. What should be the minimum VM configuration in terms of RAM, processor, disk and cache for
   Magento and mySQL. Considering the load on website can be around 3K users during peak time.

Regards,
Rajesh

Comment: For your 1. question. What is the RELEASE DATE?  If it is less than 90 days, do you have time to find, report and wait on problem correction?  Many people do not want this early adopter use of their time.

Comment: How long has the Magento application been running in PRODUCTION? On ONE server? Is it broken? If the first answer is more than one year, the second answer is yes and third answer is No, why complicate your life and the life of everyone using either system? View profile for contact info and get in touch. –

Comment: Thanks Wilson, I am going with RHEL 8.4, just 2 release before because of stability. Yes application is working fine from last 2 year, so will go single server for now.

Comment: Are you aware RHEL 8.4 eol (end of life) is posted as May 21, 2023?  Less than a year from now.  RHEL 8.5 became General Availability on 2021-11-09 and should be safe by now.

Comment: Thanks Wilson, we have delayed the deployment and will go with 8.5